# when run the url getting 404 error in custom module

Tags: magento2, module, 404, magento2-enterprise

When run the custom module getting 404 error. Anyone, please help me.

> app/code/Tychons/Registration/Block/Index.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Tychons\Registration\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $customerSession;
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $_object;
    /**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface
 */

    public function __construct(Context $context,ObjectManagerInterface $interface,array $data = []){
        $this->_object = $interface;
        //$this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->storeManager = $context->getStoreManager();
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    public function getBaseUrl()
    {
        return $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
    }



}
```

> app/code/Tychons/Registration/Controller/Verification.php

```
<?php
namespace Tychons\Registration\Controller;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory; 
class Verification extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {
    public function execute() {
            $resultPage = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);       
            $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Email Verification'));
            return $resultPage;
    }

}
```

> app/code/Tychons/Registration/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc‌​/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard"> 
        <route id="verification" frontName="verification"> 
            <module name="Tychons_Registration" /> 
        </route> 
    </router> 
</config>
```

> app/code/Tychons/Registration/view/frontend/layout/registration_verification.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" as="top"  remove="true">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Verification</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
             <block class="Tychons\Registration\Block\Index" name="verification" template="Tychons_Registration::verification.phtml" after='page.main.title' cacheable="false">
             </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/code/Tychons/Registration/view/frontend/templates/verification.phtml

```
<?php echo "verificatiob page"; ?>
```

> app/code/Tychons/Registration/registration.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Module configuration
 */
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Tychons_Registation',
    __DIR__
);
```

> app/code/Tychons/Registration/etc/module.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!--
    /**
     * Module configuration.
     */
    -->
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
            <module name="Tychons_Registration" setup_version="1.0.0" />
    </config>
```

Comment: Do you declare `module.xml` and `registration.php` files?

Comment: yes module is enabled

Comment: changed name to verification_index_index.xml and the run the url like url/verification but getting 404 error

Comment: Your xml name is verification_index_index.xml. So you have to change  controller path as app/code/Tychons/Registration/Controller/Index/Index.php
Then cache clean and check.

Comment: Your `Tychons/Registration/view/frontend/layout/registration_verification.xml` and `app/code/Tychons/Registration/Controller/Verification.php` are wrong. Please read my answer careful.

Comment: @venkataprasad check my answer again. I have fixed a bug.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, take a look here

**vendor/magento/module-store/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList" shared="true">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="standard" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base</item>
                    <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">30</item>
                </item>
                .....
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

The base router will use this class: `\Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base`

```
public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
{
    $params = $this->parseRequest($request);

    return $this->matchAction($request, $params);
}




protected function parseRequest(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
{
    ......
    foreach ($this->_requiredParams as $paramName) {
        $output[$paramName] = array_shift($params);
    }
    ......
}
```

**`protected $_requiredParams = ['moduleFrontName', 'actionPath', 'actionName'];`**

As we can see, we need 3 params, but only pass only 2 params (Your url: `verification/verification`). So, the `actionName` will be null. So the default action name will be `index`. But, we don't have `index` action too. So, 404 not found will be loaded.

Back to your code, I saw:

Your layout should be `frontMame_actionPath_actionName`.xml. `frontName` is from `etc/frontend/routes.xml`.

So, we need to create `actionName`, your controller should be:

**Tychons/Registration/Controller/Verification/Index.php**

```
<?php

namespace Tychons\Registration\Controller\Verification;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;


class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    public function execute() {
        $resultPage = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Email Verification'));
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

**Tychons/Registration/view/frontend/layout/verification_verification_index_xml => `frontname_actionPath_actionName`.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Tychons\Registration\Block\Index" name="verification" template="Tychons_Registration::verification.phtml" after='page.main.title' cacheable="false">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now, input url: `verification/verification/index` or `verification/verification`. We will see the result.

Comment: modified the files but still same 404 error

Comment: Try to clear Magento Cache. If still not working, please update your question with the latest code.

Comment: cleared the cache

Comment: Please, update your question with the latest code. Including `module.xml` and `registration.php` files.

Comment: added the module.xml and registration.php files please check.

Comment: Your controller and xml are issues. Please, follow my answer with code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75489/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-venkata-prasad).

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should be like this:

```
app/code/Tychons/Registration/Controller/Verifications/Index.php
```

instead of

```
app/code/Tychons/Registration/Controller/Verification.php
```

Now you **call** your module like this:

```
www.domaine.com/verification/verifications
```

Dont forget to run the **setup upgrade** like this: `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller path to

> Tychons/Registration/Controller/Verification/Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Tychons\Registration\Controller\Verification;

use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute() {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Email Verification'));
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Now clean the cache and remove var/generation folder if your magento version is lower than 2.2.x otherwise remove generated folder.

Now run the url as your_magento_url/verification/verification/index

Answer (score 0):

Create directory Verification in Controller folder and copy paste the controller into it, and rename it to Index.php, also change class name inside.

Change layout xml filename to verification_verification_index.xml

run cli commands:
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento s:d:c